# how to resize image without crop

Tags: c#

Here is my code.

```
//argument x contains an HTML Page
public static void ConvertHtmlToImage(string x)
{
    Bitmap m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(600, 800)
    `enter code here`;
    PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
    SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(500, 500);
    HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap), x, point, maxSize);
    if (File.Exists(@"D:\HtmlToImage.png"))
    {
        File.Delete(@"D:\HtmlToImage.png");
    }
    m_Bitmap.Save(@"D:\HtmlToImage.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    m_Bitmap.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be trying to resize the image. Can you explain what your issue is?

Comment: Why the GC.Collect at the end?

Comment: @john notice his `enter code here`

Comment: @Rand "Enter code here" does not a question make. Going back to my original point, there is absolutely no code here for resizing or cropping an image. He hasn't provided any information about what `HtmlRender.Render` is so we don't know if the code he wants to change is in there, but without providing any of this information I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: I'm trying to convert html page to image and save into local directory. but image save with croped.

Comment: And what is HtmlRender? Did you write it? Is it a library?

Comment: Looks like it's from [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_theartofdev_htmlrenderer_winforms_htmlrender.htm#!). A quick look at the API and I would guess OP needs to call the [HtmlRender.Measure Method](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/m_theartofdev_htmlrenderer_winforms_htmlrender_measure.htm) first to avoid cropping.